# How to achieve underline effect for an input - css

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the underline effect when the input is focused (-> left to right)

I saw a lot of "tricks" you can achive that with.

But I was wondering what is the most efficient way to achive this?

(Browser support wise and syntactic wise)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.input{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.input > .txt-underline{
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.underline{
  transition: all 0.5s;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
.input > .txt-underline:focus + .underline{
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <input type="text" class="txt-underline" placeholder="Please Enter Name">
  <span class="underline"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and easy example.

```css
#input {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}

span {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px; /* depending on height */
  height: 5px; /* height of span -like border */
  background: #f00;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 0 /* hidden */
}

input:hover ~ span {
  width: 100% /* full width on hover */
}
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="input" /><span></span>
</div>
```